# How to setup IAM policy for all instances controlled by an instance group manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam

I have a `google_compute_instance_group_manager` which uses a `google_compute_instance_template` to create several compute instances. I also have a `google_service_account` to which I want to grant the ability to list and inspect the instances.

There is a way to assign IAM policy for an individual instance with `google_compute_instance_iam_member` ([the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance_iam.html)), however I fail to find a way to do the same for all instances controlled by the manager. Indeed, the `google_compute_instance_iam_member` resource requires knowing the exact instance name, which is doable if you have a singe `google_compute_instance`, yet in the case of a manager-controlled group one cannot know the exact instance names, only perhaps `base_instance_name`.

How to setup IAM policy for all instances controlled by an instance group manager?

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared must have the gcloud equivalent in [instances add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-iam-policy-binding)

If you list the available gcloud commands for instance-groups it does not show any add-**iam-policy-binding** option , see screenshot , so it makes sense that is not supported by Terraform.

[image]

For what I understand you want to grant the list and get permission to an instance group so all of the current and future instances inside the group will can be listed and inspected without the need to add another binding.
This looks like a good [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)  for Google , if implemented it should be ported to Terraform